# How can I generate AI video like this one?

Tags: text-to-video

How Can I generate AI video like this one?
I tried Runway Ai, but results are always with moving camera.
I need a video with still camera shot like this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE1wyu9vxgU
Thank you!!

Comment: The video is no longer available